# Яндекс карта. Создание кастомного балуна при клике по карте

Tags: яндекс-карты

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки. 
Стоит задача создания кастомного балуна с формой для отзыва при клике по карте. При этом на самой карте нету маркеров. То-есть при клике по карте у меня должен открываться балун с формой для отзыва, после того как пользователь оставляет свой отзыва на карте остается маркер. Возможно кто-то сталкивался с подобной задачей.
Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Слушаем событие клика по карте. При клике по карте создаём новую метку и добавляем её на карту. Подходящий пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/event_reverse_geocode

Добавляем собственный контент балуна. Подходящие примеры: 
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/geoobject_contextmenu
https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_balloon_layout

Открываем у метки балун:

```
placemark.balloon.open()
```